# What is the differences between two codes?

Tags: python

What are the differences between the last lines? Why is the second one is correct, and the first one is not?

```
# I wanted to write this code like this but it is false.Because of
# line 7 and 8.
def is_authorized(my_list,m_name):
    for num in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[num].name==m_name and my_list[num].authorized==True:
            return True
        else:
            return False


# program accepts this one. If indentation of line 16 same as line
# 13.

def is_authorized(my_list,m_name):
    for num in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[num].name==m_name and my_list[num].authorized==True:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: The first one will always return after the first iteration

Comment: The top loop returns early upon hitting the first `True` or `False`. The second loop returns `False` iff none of the items in the loop fell into the `True` branch

Comment: They are very different.  The first snippet will never check anything but the first item.  You always return.  The second snippet will run through the whole list, and only if NONE of the records match will it return false.

Comment: Step through the two functions by hand to understand the difference.

Comment: BTW, get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):` Use `for item in list:`

Comment: @Barmar is right, when you don't need the index into a loop you HAVE to use a foreach loop, it's ridicoulus to use "for i in range(len())" for everything.

Comment: @Lima, you should remember that writing `boolean == True` is uncorrect, in your code you should write `mylist[num].authorized`, without the `==True`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, the for loop returns after the first item in the first case. Consider simplifying your code:

```
def is_authorized(my_list,m_name):
    return any(
        item.name == m_name and item.authorized
        for item in my_list
   )
```

Comment: This is an idiomatic solution for _testing a list of elements_ for elements meeting a specific condition (_predicate_) and returning the result = if found [`any`](https://realpython.com/any-python/). When introducing new functions or concepts elaborating links like [docs for Python's built-in `any(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) will help, especially newbies.

Answer (score 0):

##### First code

---

The first code would check only the first item, since it will return a value (`True` or `False`) even if the `if` condition is false.

```
while True:
    if (condition):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

As you can see above, the loop will be executed only once.

##### Second code

---

You will check all the array, and return `False` only if the condition is false for each `num in range(len(my_list))`.

```
while True:
    if (condition):
        return True
    return False
```

You second code has applications really similar to the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function.

## Any

---

The Python built-in function `any()`, linked above, is used like this:

```
>>> any([True, False, True])
True
>>> any([False, False])
False
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> booleans = [element > 2 for element in array]
>>> any(booleans)
```

According to the Python 3.10 documentation `any` is defined like this:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

#### Code

In your case, you can do something like the [code suggested by jak123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69682123/5730279):

```
def is_authorized(my_list,m_name):
    return any(
        item.name == m_name and item.authorized
        for item in my_list
   )
```

Comment: Your suggestion to __learn from _existing  Python code_ like `any`__ is a fantastic idea: the OP can "steal" like the [famous quote "good artists copy; great artists steal"](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/03/06/artists-steal/). But pay attention to indentation (`def any`). Furthermore good community etiquette is to credit the [answer by jak123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69682123/5730279) by name and a link. A __copy is redundant__ as duplicate without added value (DRY), a __reference/link would be enough__ ️

Comment: @hc_dev, thank you for the explaination, really usefull for the future.